# About the method of accelerating scip and parameter setting

Tags: scip

About the method of accelerating scip and parameter setting

I want to improve the speed of the solution by setting some parameters, and I don't require the optimal solution, how can I get it quickly?

I looked at the parameters in https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/PARAMETERS.php but didn't really understand them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by experimenting with [SCIP emphasis settings](https://www.scipopt.org/doc-8.0.3/html/FAQ.php#howtochangebehaviour). That lets you change a bunch of parameters at once. If you want to focus on quickly finding good solutions then you should try to use aggressive heuristics.

If you do not want to focus on proving optimality, then you could think about disabling separation.